# How To Make a game-restart if player movement was stopped

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I looking to create a game , in the game scene i have i SKNode called "player" the player moving by touch , what i need to do is : how i can make you lose the Game if you stopped the "player" movement , keep the "player" moving , i used touch ended method but its not what i Need
If you seen the rubby bird game you can have a idea about what i need. what i Mean In all of that is , if the player speed = 0 then restart the Game . and the player speed befor the movement is player.sped= 3;

> `-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{
>   player.speed = 0
>   }`...

Any Suggestion will help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best place to track your objects such a player and other nodes is:

```
- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime;
```

Here you can check if your players speed not change. if speed is change then show new scene. Here is pseudocode

```
    - (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
    {
        // check player collisions
        // after that check players speed  
        if (player.speed <= 0)
        {
           // show another scene and restart the game
           EndScene *scene = [EndScene sceneWithSize:viewSize];

          // draw label
          SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
          myLabel.text = @"Game Over";
          myLabel.fontSize = 20;
          myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),         CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
          [scene addChild:myLabel];

          [self presentScene: scene];
        }
        // else if speed is still > 0 and game continuing, so nothing to do
    }
```

*EDIT*
I understand your problem, so there are plenty ways to do that:
1) You can use your touch method and always save user finger position, so if on next calling of this method position not changed in right direction, then he lose;
2) you can upgrade my "update" method to get delta between players touch position.

```
- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    // Handle time delta.
    // If we drop below 60fps, we still want everything to move the same distance.
    CFTimeInterval timeSinceLast = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
    self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
    if (timeSinceLast > kMinTimeInterval) { // more than a second since last update
        timeSinceLast = kMinTimeInterval;
        self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
        self.worldMovedForUpdate = YES;
    }

    [self updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:timeSinceLast];
}

- (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(NSTimeInterval)timeSinceLast
{
    // here you get timeSinceLast update loop, so here you know touch position from last iteration and touch position from current iteration
}
```

Keep me posted

Comment: Thank You Dear @gronzzz For Answer , I Used Your Code There But i Still Have The Same Problem .exactly what i want to do Watch on youtube ((RubbyBird)) Game You Will Understand what i mean bro  but in my case the player is moving between tow points not frozen like the bird in the ((rubbyBird)) Game,, thanx again waiting your answer

Comment: ok i understand your problem, update my post

Comment: Guys I Still Have The Same Problem .. Let Me Be More Clearly (Lets Say I Want To Make My SKNode " Player" SWIPING between tow points  By Touch ,and you have to keep swiping and if you stop swiping the game will end )...Thanks For Help

Comment: When you swipe, player coordinate always updates and touch coordinate also, so you have update method, you have 2 coordinate and delta between them, what's a problem to calculate them and if delta == 0, then show lose screen ?